# virtual functions with a non-void return type

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Consider the following inheritance and composition scheme.

// Example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

class TapProcessing
{
    public:
          TapProcessing(){};
          virtual ~TapProcessing(){};

          virtual void getWeights(valarray<double> &weights) {};
          virtual void getPrecisionWeights (valarray<double> &precWeights) {};
          virtual const uint &getTapIndex(const uint index) const
          {
              valarray<uint> a;
              a.resize(10);
              return a[index];
          }; //const {return 0;};
          virtual const uint &getTapIndexLow(const uint index) const
          {
              valarray<uint> a;
              a.resize(10);
              return a[index];
          }; //const {return 0;};;
          virtual const uint &getTapIndexHigh(const uint index) const
          {
              valarray<uint> a;
              a.resize(10);
              return a[index];
          }; //const {return 0;};

};

class StepPrecisionTapProcessing : public TapProcessing
{
    public:
        StepPrecisionTapProcessing() { _tapIndex.resize(10, 3); }
        ~StepPrecisionTapProcessing() {};

        void getWeights(valarray<double> &weights) { return weights.resize(10);}
        virtual const uint &getTapIndex(const uint index) const {return _tapIndex[index]; }

    private:
          valarray<uint> _tapIndex;

};

class HighPrecisionTapProcessing : public TapProcessing
{
    public:
        HighPrecisionTapProcessing()
        {
            _tapIndexLow.resize(10, 4);
            _tapIndexHigh.resize(10, 5);
        }
        ~HighPrecisionTapProcessing() {};

        void getPrecisionWeights (valarray<double> &precWeights) { return precWeights.resize(10); };
        virtual const uint &getTapIndexLow(const uint index) const {return _tapIndexLow[index]; }
        virtual const uint &getTapIndeHigh(const uint index) const {return _tapIndexHigh[index]; }

    private:
          valarray<uint> _tapIndexLow;
          valarray<uint> _tapIndexHigh;

};

class Generator
{
    public:
           Generator(bool isPrecision)
           {
               if (isPrecision) {_tp = new HighPrecisionTapProcessing();
               }
               else { _tp = new StepPrecisionTapProcessing(); }
           }

           ~Generator() { delete _tp; }

           const uint &getTapIndex(const uint index) const {return _tp->getTapIndex(index); }
           const uint &getTapIndexLow(const uint index) const {return _tp->getTapIndexLow(index); }
           const uint &getTapIndexHigh(const uint index) const {return _tp->getTapIndexHigh(index); }

    private:
           TapProcessing *_tp;
};



int main()
{
  Generator *G = new Generator(true);
  uint index = 5;

  cout<<"High tap index is = "<<G->getTapIndexHigh(index)<<endl;

  delete G;
  return 0;
}
```

When I run main, I get the following output,

> High tap index is = 0

Here if the declaration of getTapIndeHigh in the derived class overrides the declaration in the base class, we would see a value of 5 in the output rather than 0. Why is derived class implementation not overriding base that of class method for non-void virtual methods?

Comment: "Is it possible to have a virtual function with a non-void return type?"  Did you try it?  " Can I give a dummy return value which will be overridden by the derived class getter?"  It seems you're missing some fairly fundamental understanding of what a virtual function is.  There's no such thing as a "dummy return value".   It's either the return value of the function called or it's not.   Do you want a pure virtual function?   That's a virtual function with no definition in the base class.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions

Comment: The compiler cannot tell for sure that `G` is an instance of a `HighPrecisionTapProcessing` object. If, for example, `G` was an instance of `StepPrecisionTapProcessing`, what exactly do you expect `G->getTapIndexHigh(index)` to return? Since there is no declaration for a function `StepPrecisionTapProcessing::getTapIndexHigh(uint)`, runtime would call the base function `TapProcessing::getTapIndexHigh(uint)`, for which you didn't provide a definition with a return value. The compiler needs the function `virtual uint TapProcessing::getTapIndexHigh(uint)` to return a `uint` value.

Comment: You want a Generator to actually contain a particular type of TapProcessing, but to have a general interface and implementation.  I'm not sure why you'd want that, but If that's really what you want, then I'd make your TapProcesing base class throw exceptions (before a never executed return if the compiler still complains) in its implementations of the functions, which your derived classes will override.  That way if you call the wrong function on a Generator that isn't supported by the underlying type you'll get an exception at runtime slapping you for not knowing the actual underlying type.

Comment: If you go the route I suggested, then the need for the Generator class largely disappears -- at least in this example.  Just have a TapProcessing unique_ptr that you initialize with either a new HighPrecisionTapProcessing or a new StepPrecisionProcessing object and you are good to go.  Oh, you probably want to make TapProcessing's destructor virtual too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from these lines...

```
      virtual uint getTapIndex(uint index) {};
      virtual uint getTapIndexLow(uint index) {};
      virtual uint getTapIndexHigh(uint index) {};
```

They describe a function which returns a `uint`, provides an implementation, but does not actually return a value.

If there is a sensible base implementation, then it is good to provide it.  However here, it seems you want a `pure virtual` method, making your class `abstract`.  You want all the derived classes to implement a value.  e.g.

```
      virtual uint getTapIndex(uint index) =0;  // require derived classes to implement
      virtual uint getTapIndexLow(uint index) { return 0 } // can be overridden, but defaults to returning zero.
      virtual uint getTapIndexHigh(uint index) = 0; // require derived classes to implement.
```

Comment: So the problem is I don't want to implement getTapIndexHigh and getTapIndexLow in StepPrecisionTapProcessing and likewise getTapIndex in HighPrecisionTapProcessing as they don't belong there. Making them pure virtual will force me to implement all three methods in both classes which sort of defeats the purpose of polymorphism in this scenario.